# Выдает ошибку error A2101: cannot add two relocatable labels(строка 26 и 27)

Tags: ассемблер

Программа должна приравнять элементы 2 массива к элементам 1 массива, если такие присутствуют. Как исправить ошибку, ребят?

```
.486
.model flat, stdcall
option casemap :none   

include \masm32\include\windows.inc
include \masm32\include\masm32.inc
include \masm32\include\kernel32.inc
include \masm32\macros\macros.asm
includelib \masm32\lib\masm32.lib
includelib \masm32\lib\kernel32.lib

.data
mas1 dd 1,2,3,4,5,6 ; инициализация 1 массива
mas2 dd 7,8     ; инициализация 2 массива

.code

start:

mov bp,0  ; 0-ой элемент массива mas2
mov di,1  ; выборка с какого элемента массива будет начало замены

mov cx, 2; счетчик, с которого будет при каждом повторении цикла отниматься 1

metka:
 mov si, mas2[bp] ;
 mov mas1[di], si
 inc bp
 inc di
 loop metka 


end start
```

Comment: Во-первых - в ошибке должен быть указан номер строки, в которой ошибка. Укажите это в вопросе. Во-вторых, у вас прямо в коде (после метки `start`) объявлены два массива, так делать нельзя, иначе процессор подумает что это код, а не данные, и попытается их выполнить. Перенесите массивы в секцию данных. В-третьих вот тут что-то не то: `mov mov[p], al` (mov вместо имени массива?). Ну и в-четвертых, ошибка скорее всего здесь: `mov al, mas2[k]`. Ассемблер - это не Си, в качестве индекса не получится использовать значение переменной, сначала его нужно положить в регистр.

Comment: Ну, значит я угадал

Comment: Все вышеперечисленное исправил. Только вот не пойму, я же записываю элемент массива mas2[k] в регистр si и потом, из этого регистра записываю значение в элемент массива mas1[p]. Что здесь не так, ведь я положил в регистр..

Comment: Я про k и p. На ассемблере нельзя адресовать массивы через индексы, лежащие в переменных (k и p в данном случае), как раз их нужно положить регистры. Получается, что вы пытаетесь в одной строке вытащить значение переменной k из памяти, потом еще раз получить значение из памяти по адресу mas2 + значение k. Это два обращения к памяти, так не получится сделать.

Comment: Да, все сделал, использовал регистры si, bp,di (16-разрядные), но пишет, что instractions operands  must be the same size

Comment: Используйте 32 битные регистры. Чтобы не ошибиться - везде)

Comment: Еще, лучше не редактировать вопрос, а оставить со всеми проблемами что были изначально. Я позже напишу ответ с разбором и рекомендациями.

Comment: У меня почему-то не те значения выводятся... а скорее адрес
Я вот так проверял 
mov ECX, mas1[0]
mov EBX, mas1[1]
mov EAX, mas1[2]
mov EDX, mas1[3]

Можешь в свой дебагер забить?

Comment: Я программу не компилировал, я по тексту вижу проблемы. При записи вот так `mov ECX, mas1[0]` записывать действительно нужно в байтовый регистр, иначе будет загружаться по 4 байта из массива, а не по одному.